# how can I use ng-if based on url in the index.html page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, ng-hide, js-routes

I want to use ng-hide in the index page if the url in some nested views.
in my index.html, I want something like:

```
    <top-bar ng-if="!home"></top-bar>
    <ui-view class="reveal-animation"></ui-view>
    <bottom-bar ng-if="!home"></bottom-bar>
```

I want that when I enter to "home" view the bars will disappeared.
as I saw here in same questions - the answer was to use $location in the controller, but where is the controller of the index page?

thanks

Comment: ngRoute will fix your problem. set predefined routes first for your entire application.

Comment: how can I use ngRoutes to pass the location information to the index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a parent controller, add the following:

```
$scope.isHome = function(){
  return $state.is("home");
}
```

Then change your template like this:

```
<top-bar ng-if="!isHome()"></top-bar>
<ui-view class="reveal-animation"></ui-view>
<bottom-bar ng-if="!isHome()"></bottom-bar>
```

[Check this plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l7mBlO4RgvCfsiPbRhTV?p=preview) to see some live code.

---

Another method would be using `$stateChangeSuccess`, something like this:

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState){
  $scope.isHome = (toState.name == "home")
})
```

I also recommend checking out `$state.includes`, `$state.current` and others. Just get through the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params)

Comment: but what is the parent controller of the index?

Comment: i hava child controllers to the views, but not to the index.html

Comment: Look, in my example, the `<ui-view>` has a controller, right? When you're in home state, it has one controller, when you're in state1, it has another, and so on for all states you declare in the config. But, because it has a controller assigned to it, it also has a scope, so whatever you put inside that scope will be accessible only inside `<ui-view>` and not outside. In your case, the variable `home` needs to be in a scope, but that scope cannot be the scope of the `<ui-view>` because you need it outside of that element.

Comment: That's why you need a parent controller, one that wraps the view and the top-bar and the bottom-bar. In my example, I assigned a parent controller for everything inside the html, but it's not necessarily to be like that. You can just wrap your code inside a `<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl"><!--top-bar & ui-view & bottom-bar here--></div>` and put that `isHome` function inside it. Now that function is in a scope accessible to all 3 elements, top-bar & ui-view & bottom-bar.

Comment: I suggest taking it easy, you need to spend some time to learn the AngularJS basics. Try angular-route first, ui-router is more advanced and it will make your life harder if you're just learning. Good luck and be patient, I have one year experience with angular and I didn't learn over night. I didn't even use ui-router until recently.

Comment: I learned a lot from this guy: https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs?order=ASC

Comment: At the end i use rootscope from othe controller what do you think about that?

Comment: It'll do the job, as $rootScope is a parent scope for all scopes, but it's considered to be bad practice :P

Answer (score -1):

It is not easy to teach you everything in one go. You have to refer to few concept.

```
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/
```

I hope this link will help you to getting started with Angularjs.

Comment: SO answers should provide some feedback along with an explanation and then refer to an outside link.